# The issue of reading the case of quartz tables after integrating quartz and springboot

Tags: quartz

When deploying the Spring Boot integrated Quratz framework in Linux, MySQL is not case sensitive in Windows, and Linux is case sensitive, resulting in the inability to find Quratz related tables such as (QRTZ_LOCKS). How to fix this bug without modifying the MySQL configuration file

Change the table to uppercase,